# Xamarin ADFS library

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, adfs

I am wondering if there are any known and reliable ADFS library for Xamarin?
I want to implement an example login and retrieve credentials from my company services.

Which means, I need to make my app aware of federation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't know of any WS-Fed implementations but it's not a good fit because the passive profile relies on browser redirects.

Have a look at [Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-ios](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-ios).

This uses OpenID Connect which accomplishes much the same thing.

Also look at Auth0.

Answer (score 1):

`OAuth2` implementation in `AD FS` is not very good in itself and rather badly documented.

For one thing, some of the parameters differ from the standard (`scope` instead on `resource`), making it hard to find any library that supports it.

Furthermore, it only supports half the standard, [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) and ignores the part of the standard about token revocation ([RFC7009](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009)).

So I made my own fork of `Xamarin.Auth`. I had to change a few things to get it to work with `AD FS`. But the `Xamarin.Auth` component in itself is of doubtful quality, not maintained and only supports iOS and Android. After running into a few bugs, even though they were easy ones to fix, I dropped `Xamarin.Auth` and did my own implementation using `Xamarin.Forms`'s `WebView`.

Comment: did you find any library that supports scope instead on a resource?